# Pronunciation of 何

Tags: pronunciation

I would like to know the pronunciation of "何" in the following clause:

子供に頼まれていることは、何かという質問に対してご返答致します。

Is it なに or なん?

I am wondering because the pronunciation of 何 can change.

子供に何（なに）が頼まれているのかという質問に対してご返答致します。

子供に頼まれていることは、何（なん）でしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, 「何」 in 「子供に頼まれていることは、何かという質問に対してご返答致します。」is pronounced なに.